# getDate returning wrong value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to set a date with 4 days range (From: today - 2, To: today + 2).
Today, on 31. august I found the bug in my code, which says `Invalid date`.
I'm changing the date like this, and If I `console.log()` it, it says `-1`.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
date: Date = new Date();
defaultDay: string = ("0" + (this.date.getDate() - 2)).slice(-2)
```

P.S: I checked the moment.JS library, but currently I don't have that much time to change the whole project to it.

Comment: This should give you an idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing the basic arithmetic. Subtracting 2 from 1 will result in -1. You may try to set the date first and then get the day from the date object.

The reason is that [`setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) sets the day relatively when the argument is not in the range (less than or equal to 0).

```js
let start = new Date();
let end = new Date();
start.setDate(start.getDate() - 2);
end.setDate(end.getDate() + 2);
console.log(start.getDate(), end.getDate());
```

Comment: Yes, I came across that solution. But I wonder if it is possible to do that without setting new Date two times?

Comment: @HC1122 -- Not sure why don't you want to set the day? Is there a restriction? This seems a correct approach, which works in all scenarios.

Comment: It is not the problem in setting date, I just wonder if it is possible without intializing two dates (start and end, so to have only one of those).

Comment: @HC1122 -- Not sure if it is too easy in plain JS.

Comment: Well, than I'm gonna use that solution. Thank you for your help, will accept answer in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

you can use date api for avoid issues.
here is an example

```js
let date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 2);
console.log(("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2));
```

but you have to remember that if you do not want to modify date itself then you have to clone it

Answer (score 0):

You can always do in a way @31piy has suggested. But Date handling is lot easier if you do it using [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/docs/).

You can do it easily like

```
const today = moment()
const two_days_after_today = moment().add(2, 'day')
const two_days_before_today = moment().subtract(2, 'day')
```

Comment: Like I said, I'm aware of it, but it's not the right time to use it.